# How to align desktop icons to grid in LXDE/Openbox?

Tags: desktop, icons, grid, openbox, lxde

Where is the option or config file to align the desktop icons to a grid in LXDE/Openbox?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You highlight the icons you want, then you right click on one of them and you select from the menu that is popping to **"Align to grid"** and automatically they will align to grid.

Comment: Right, thanks, I didn't say that I want them to be aligned automatically. Right-click and "Align to grid" aligns them, but as soon as I move an icon, it's not aligned anymore.